# Is there an INSERT syntax that allows visual symmetry between columns and values?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-insert

The (normal) `INSERT` sytnax looks like this (disregarding personal choices of line breaks / parenthesis placements):

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (
  Col1,
  Col2,
  ...
) VALUES (
  @value1,
  @value2
  ...
)
```

Since the association between the column and the value is based on the index in two different lists, as it were, this can become unwieldy if you have many columns. If you need to change something, you might end up changing the wrong column, or you risk inserting the value for `Col15` in `Col16` and vice versa because both were of compatible types and thus the query runs without problems.

I have previously "worked around" it like this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable ( Col1,  SomeCol2,  Col3WithLongName,  Col4, ...)
             VALUES (@col1, @someCol2, @col3WithLongName, @col4, ...)
```

This, of course, has its own problems in that the lines can become *very* long (and it's not particularly fun to manually align code).

Ideally I'd like an `UPDATE`-like syntax for `INSERT`, which AFAIK isn't possible but would look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (
  Col1 = @value1,
  Col2 = @value2,
  ...
)
```

Here, the association between column and value is immediately clear. I know there are often several different syntaxes for the same thing in T-SQL, but I haven't found an `INSERT` syntax that has this quality (clear column/value mapping).

Is there an `INSERT` syntax that has this quality, at least to a larger extent?

(If it's relevant, I'm mostly wondering about this in the context of `MERGE`.)

Comment: No, the syntax for an `INSERT` is `INSERT INTO {Table} ({Delimited Column List} ) VALUES({Delimited Values List}){,({Delimited Values List})};` or `INSERT INTO {Table} ({Delimited Column List} ) SELECT {Columns} FROM...`. That is how the language is defined, and it is not specific to T-SQL that's how all the SQL language work.

Comment: *If* you are inserting into *all* the columns in the destination table, you can omit the `{Delimited Column List}`, however, and the values with be inserted into the columns based on their ordinal positions in the table. That is ***only*** true if you are inserting into *all* of the columns though. If you had a table with 50 columns, and you wanted to only insert into 48 of them, this would not work.

Comment: ... And, to add to @Larnu's last comment - that is a very bad idea because as soon as the table structure changes the insert statement will break.

Comment: Also, a syntax like you're looking for will only support a single row insert - while the existing insert syntax supports multiple rows either by means of multiple values (`values (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)`) or by using `insert ... select`.

Comment: IIRC, Redgate's SQL Prompt add on for SSMS, which is a paid product, has a feature where the placing your cursor onto an item in the `INSERT` list highlights the corresponding item in the `VALUES` or `SELECT` list.